# C# google contact api deleted contact

Tags: c#, events, outlook, history, google-contacts-api

currently I´m writing on a outlook plugin for syncing goolge contacts with outlook but I have to cover some special case:

When a contact gets deleted on google side, my application detects the missing contact and creates a new contact based on the contact info from the outlook one.
Is there a way to get an event or history from google that tells me a user deleted this contact(s)?

Edit 1:
Here is my code how I´m accessing the contacts (what is working FINE):

```
public GoogleAccessor()
{
    var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters()
    {
        ClientId = CLIENTID,
        ClientSecret = CLIENTSECRET,
        RedirectUri = REDIRECTURI,
        Scope = SCOPES
    };

    string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
    //An own webbrowser for processing the access tokens
    IAuthorizationCodeProvider authcodeProvider = new Presentation.BrowserAuthorizationCodeProvider(new Presentation.BrowserAuthentificatorVM());
    parameters.AccessCode = authcodeProvider.GetAuthorizationCode(url);

    if(parameters.AccessCode == null)
        throw new GoogleOAuthException("AccesCode returned 'null' and failed!");

    OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);

    this._contactsRequest = new ContactsRequest(new RequestSettings(APPLICATIONNAME, parameters) {AutoPaging = true});
}
public IList<IContact> GetAllMappedContacts()
{
    Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> f = _contactsRequest.GetContacts();
    this._feedUri = new Uri(f.AtomFeed.Feed);
    var photoList = new List<PhotoObject>();

    foreach (var entry in f.Entries)
    {
        var photoObject = GetContactPhoto(entry);
        if(photoObject != null)
            photoList.Add(photoObject);
    }
    _googleMapper = new GoogleMapper(f.Entries);
    return _googleMapper.MapToLocalContacts();;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the code that is completing the sync?

Comment: This is confusing sorry. You are implying that you are trying to 'push' your Outlook contacts to Google right? So are you wanting to be able to remove a contact from Google that was previously synced from Outlook, and not have the contact repopulate in Google every time a sync is reaccomplished?

Comment: Yes exactly, if I don´t know that a contact was deleted by the user, my tool would push the missing contact every time to google.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about syncing in general is that syncing is normally meant to work in one direction.

Source Data -> Data Flow -> Received Data.

In this instance, Outlook is your source data and Google is your received data. All information needs to come from your source. Since this is an Outlook add-in you are creating my suggestion would be to add a button to your add-in ribbon. You can call the button whatever ever you like (maybe "dontSyncButton"), but it's purpose is going to be Categorization of your contact.

Make it so that that when a contact is selected and then the button is clicked, the contact is given a special categorization (perhaps "Dont Sync").

Now give some logic to your code that executes the sync, and have that logic decide whether to sync the contact. Also, give some logic to tell the program to delete the contact out of Google for you if the contacts contains the special category. Semi-Pseudo Code below:

```
 if(contact.Categories.ToString() == "Dont Sync")
 {
     //Don't Sync Contact
     If(googleContact.Exists())
     {
         //Delete contact from Google if it exist
         googleContact.Delete();
     } 
 }
 else
 {
     //Sync Contact
 }
```

It would be nice if Outlook had many modifiable properties that weren't visible to users, but since it does not this is really one of the best options I can think of. I do this to sync contacts from a shared Outlook folder to personal ones and it has worked well so far.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I´m already writing an addin, and my sync works in both ways, but the difficulty is to detect that a user deleted a contact on purpose.
I know there would some other solutions like that you described, but I don´t want to confuse the users with such special operations.