# Outlook ContactItem DeleteEvent

Tags: c#, events, add-in, outlook-addin

Currently I´m writing a sync tool for GMail contacts and outlook, but there is a little problem:
I need an event in my addin when the user deletes a contact, otherwise the sync tool would detect the missing contact on the outlook side and the tool will create the contact from the google side.

I´m accessing all Outlook contacts from the default folder with this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = GetCurrentNamespace();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder contacts = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

IList<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem> items = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem>();

foreach (var contact in contacts.Items)
{
    items.Add(contact as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem);
}

return items;
```

Edit 1:
I already tried to subscribe to an BeforeDelete Event as John Saunders commented, but with no success. When I try to delete a contact in Outlook the event wont get fired.

Code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = GetCurrentNamespace();
_contactMapiFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

//IList<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem> items = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem>();
this._contacts = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem>();

foreach (var contact in _contactMapiFolder.Items)
{
    Outlook.ContactItem item = contact as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem;
    item.BeforeDelete += ItemOnBeforeDelete;
    this._contacts.Add(item);
}

return this._contacts;
```

Can anybody provide me an example what events are available for such mapi (especially contact folders) folders are available and how they are working?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: sorry, didn´n know that :\

Comment: Yea I read some msdn articles and docus, but the office addin development documentation is not very well documented

Comment: I´m searching for a ItemDeleted or BeforeItemDeleted for the default contact folder, in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder object there are no events defined.

Comment: Yea thats the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508640/c-sharp-google-contact-api-deleted-contact
If google wont notify me that a user deleted a contact, I´m not able to delete the contact in outlook. Deleting a contact object is no problem, but to get an event from outlook it is.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868306.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

It is a really bad idea to set up an event sink on each and every item in a folder.

When `Items.ItemRemove` even fires, there is no way for you to figure out which item was deleted. You have no choice but to compare the current collection with what you have on the server or in some kind of local cache.

You can try to use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOItems](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`ItemRemove` event - it passes the value of the `PR_INSTANCE_KEY` MAPI property from the folder contents table. If you cache the values of the `PR_INSTANCE_KEY` property for all items ahead of time (you can use `RDOITems.MAPITable.ExecSQL` for that), you can figure out which item was deleted without looping through all items in the folder.

Comment: Hmm ok that might be a solution, but I don´t want want so buy an external tool

Comment: You can either

1. Use Items.ItemRemove event as a trigger to reconcile the present folder items with your cache to figure out which item got deleted.

2. Switch to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) that will give you the PR_INSTANCE_KEY property when fnevTableModified /  TABLE_ROW_DELETED event fires

Comment: My two cents, WhiteIntel: Redemption is an *essential* tool IMHO for Outlook development. I've been building Outlook solutions for 14 years and use it in 90% of my projects. It is packed with features and saves you time.